# app crash when next control in FocusSearch isn't focusable on Telerik dataform

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, telerik

Currently our app is using version 3.5 of xamarin forms and on android the app crashes when you tap next/done on any data entry text field with the error message: 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: focus search returned a view that wasn't able to take focus'. iOS remains unaffected.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5030

The Githib page above suggests changing the controls ImeOptions in custom renderer as a temporary workaround. I don't believe I can implement this due to using Telerik dataforms.

To sum up, does anyone know how i can either implement the workaround stated at the GitHub link, or know of any other solutions/workaround using Telerik Dataforms

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please post a demo so that we can test it for you?

Comment: This is a known issue reported on xamarin GitHub, so i assume they are still looking into it. For the time being i have found a workaround using a custom data form renderer. Thank you anyway :)

workaround - https://feedback.telerik.com/xamarin/1366529-dataform-android-exception-is-thrown-when-pressing-next-button-on-the-keyboard-on-xf-3-3-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue with xamarin form editors on android only. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4832

Workaround found - implement a custom dataform renderer.
https://feedback.telerik.com/xamarin/1366529-dataform-android-exception-is-thrown-when-pressing-next-button-on-the-keyboard-on-xf-3-3-0